# Hiding Responsive menu on link click

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a Responsive mobile navigation menu.

I'm having a few problems, on trying to work out how to do everything.

Wanted to know how to hide my Responsive drop down menu once i have clicked on a link.

Also how would i style it so that when its a full size website the menu items show next to each other on the top right of screen?

```css
#NavBar {
    position: fixed;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #3498db;
    z-index: 1;
}

/*Create a horizontal list with spacing*/

li {
    list-style-type: none;
    height: 40px;
}

/*Style for menu links*/

li a {
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

/*Style 'show menu' label button and hide it by default*/

.show-menu {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px 0;
    display: none;
}

/*Hide checkbox*/

input[type=checkbox] {
    display: none;
}

/*Show menu when invisible checkbox is checked*/

input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ #menu {
    display: block;
}


@media screen and (max-width: 760px) {
    /*Make dropdown links appear inline*/
    ul {
        /*        position: static;*/
        display: none;
    }

    /*Display 'show menu' link*/
    .show-menu {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="NavBar">
    <label for="show-menu" class="show-menu">Show Menu</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="show-menu" role="button">
    <ul id="menu">
        <li><a href="#Home" class="item">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#AboutUs" class="item">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#Gallery" class="item">Gallery</a></li>
        <li><a href="#ContactUs" class="item">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: *'how would i style it so that when its a full size website...'* Use media queries

Comment: hey you can try using this examples:
[drop-down-navigation-responsive](https://osvaldas.info/drop-down-navigation-responsive-and-touch-friendly)

[dropdown](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_dropdown.asp)

[topnav_responsive](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_topnav_responsive.asp)

Comment: @nathan Are you looking for only css solution?

Comment: @Znaneswar yess im looking for only css if i can

Comment: @AbhishekPandey yeah that was a dumb question, i worked that out

Comment: There is no way to do this without javascript. You have to go with this.